# Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP sometimes uses proxy, need to disallow this

Tags: vbscript

We have a custom security solution in our domain. Upon startup the PC runs a vb-script (through group policy) in which it tries to make HTTP POST to external server. If it succeeds, PC is marked for inspection (direct access to Internet is disallowed).

The problem is that on some PCs this script somehow successfully sends POST, but we checked and 100% sure that there is no direct access to Internet (even no routing).

My code is:

```
objXmlHttp.open "POST", "http://hostingIP:80/catcher/collctrr", False
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=cp1251"
objXmlHttp.send ("pc="&URLE(strComputer)&"&ip="&URLE(strIP)&"&d="&URLE(StrDomain)&"&u="&URLE(StrUser))
```

We do not touch **setProxy** method. Is it possible to force "no proxy mode"?

We still have some winXPs, so should be staying with vbs. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the [setProxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method

```
oSrvXMLHTTPRequest.setProxy(proxySetting, varProxyServer, varBypassList);
```

indicates that the `proxySetting` argument can be

> **1** : **SXH_PROXY_SET_DIRECT**
>
> The SXH_PROXY_SET_DIRECT option can be used to specify that all HTTP
>   and HTTPS servers should be accessed directly.

Comment: Thank you! Was using "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP" and it doesn't support this method, but "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0" is OK and even working in clean winxp sp3.